# Microsoft.Web.Administration: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, iis

When Adding a binding to IIS using `Microsoft.Web.Administration` with code like this:

```
var newBinding = Site.Bindings.CreateElement();
newBinding.BindingInformation = bindingInformation;
var existingSsl = // some code that finds an existing SSL binding to copy off
var sslFlags = SslFlags.Sni;
if (existingSsl != null)
{
    newBinding.Protocol = existingSsl.Protocol;
    newBinding.CertificateHash = existingSsl.CertificateHash;
    newBinding.CertificateStoreName = existingSsl.CertificateStoreName;
}

Site.Bindings.Add(newBinding.BindingInformation, newBinding.CertificateHash, newBinding.CertificateStoreName, sslFlags);
```

I get an exception

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostMethodInstance.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationMethodInstance.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding.AddSslCertificate(Byte[] certificateHash, String certificateStoreName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingManager.BindingTransaction.Commit()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingManager.Save()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.CommitChanges()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bindingInformation` value that was failing was of format `*:443:` - meaning there was no host header information.

In that case, the `SNI` flag is an illegal flag. SNI can only be used when a hostheader is specified.

The trick to discovering this (rather obvious in hindsight) error was to try and mirror the settings that are being applied in the UI. The UI has validation which helps show what illegal thing you are attempting.