Create installer which can create the Self signed certificate and host the application by binding certificate using .Net
var binding = site.Bindings.Add("*:443:", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(certThumbprint), StoreName.My.ToString());
binding.Protocol = "https";
serverManager.CommitChanges();

I tried to create the Self signed certificate and tried to bind get the issue such as

Value doesn't fall within the expected range


This error may be that there was no host header information, similar questions you can use as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208552/microsoft-web-administration-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range.
